# Query that returns quantity of repeated values

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I need a query that returns the quantity of repeated values in the field "Info" of my table "Log".

Table Log:

```
ID_Log         User    Info
   1            1       3
   2            1       3
   3            1       3
   4            1       5
   5            1       6
   6            1       6
   7            1       7
   8            1       8
   9            1       8
```

The query should return "4" (Info 3 appears three times, Info 6 appears two times, Info 8 appears two times).

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does 3 `3`s plus 2 `6`s plus 2 `8`s get us to an answer of `4`?  Do you mean that you want the number of times a value we've already seen appears again?

Comment: Exactly, That's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of values that have already appeared by using a simple subtraction.  Subtract the number of distinct values from the total number of rows:

```
select count(*) - count(distinct info)
from log;
```

The difference is the number that "repeat".

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Group the values of info together and only keep the results where the number of occurrences minus 1 is greater than 0.  Then sum the numbers of occurrences.

```
select sum(repeats)
from (SELECT Info, count(*) - 1 AS repeats
      FROM   Log
      GROUP  BY Info
      HAVING repeats > 0)
```

Comment: Ah, well, Gordon's answer is better than mine!